# Running cpu intensive task in android device

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app in android in which I need to monitor CPU usage vs power consumption. In order to do that I some thing weird:

I need to run some computationally expensive task, which can use as much CPU as possible.

I dont want that task to use any other component like LCD, audio, wifi etc.Just pure CPU.

If you guys have any answer to this weird sort of question please help...
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't simply an infinite loop calculating for instance some factorial random number do the job?

Answer (score 0):

There are several, like finding prime numbers by brute force, Ackermann Function, or Travelling Salesman for example.